# All Table options in one package

Tags: tables, tabularx, tabulary, supertabular

I have gone through `tabular`, `longtable`, `tabulary`, `tabularx`, `supertabular`, i want to know which of these packages or any other packages support all kinds of table options like mentioned below,

1. Auto width for columns,
2. Decimal alignment, etc support,
3. Table Continued style for both single and double column,
4. Table landscape option

and if so, please provide us a minimal example of that package with all options, which will be useful beginners like us

Table Sample

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Table sample}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\hline
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4 \\ \hline
1 &  1  &        1  &           1    \\
2   &     4  &       16  &           2    \\
3   &     9  &       81  &           6    \\
4   &    16  &      256  &          24    \\[5mm]
5   &    25  &      625  &         120    \\
6   &    36  &     1296  &         720    \\
7   &    49  &     2401  &        5040    \\
8   &    64  &     4096  &       40320    \\
9   &    81  &     6561  &      362880    \\
10  &   100  &    10000  &     3628800    \\
1 &  1  &        1  &           1    \\
2   &     4  &       16  &           2    \\
3   &     9  &       81  &           6    \\
4   &    16  &      256  &          24    \\[5mm]
5   &    25  &      625  &         120    \\
6   &    36  &     1296  &         720    \\
7   &    49  &     2401  &        5040    \\
8   &    64  &     4096  &       40320    \\
9   &    81  &     6561  &      362880    \\
10  &   100  &    10000  &     3628800    \\
1 &  1  &        1  &           1    \\
2   &     4  &       16  &           2    \\
3   &     9  &       81  &           6    \\
4   &    16  &      256  &          24    \\[5mm]
5   &    25  &      625  &         120    \\
6   &    36  &     1296  &         720    \\
7   &    49  &     2401  &        5040    \\
8   &    64  &     4096  &       40320    \\
9   &    81  &     6561  &      362880    \\
10  &   100  &    10000  &     3628800    \\
1 &  1  &        1  &           1    \\
2   &     4  &       16  &           2    \\
3   &     9  &       81  &           6    \\
4   &    16  &      256  &          24    \\
5   &    25  &      625  &         120    \\
6   &    36  &     1296  &         720    \\
7   &    49  &     2401  &        5040    \\
8   &    64  &     4096  &       40320    \\
9   &    81  &     6561  &      362880    \\
10  &   100  &    10000  &     3628800    \\
1 &  1  &        1  &           1    \\
2   &     4  &       16  &           2    \\
3   &     9  &       81  &           6    \\
4   &    16  &      256  &          24    \\
5   &    25  &      625  &         120    \\
6   &    36  &     1296  &         720    \\
7   &    49  &     2401  &        5040    \\
8   &    64  &     4096  &       40320    \\
9   &    81  &     6561  &      362880    \\
10  &   100  &    10000  &     3628800    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

To minimize my query, say for example, how to make this table autofit as well as table continued style for both single and double column

Comment: I, honestly, I did not understand the meaning of your question.

Comment: @Sebastiano I guess he wants to know what is the best table package for his four needs. In addition, the helper should provide a MWE, so that he has a smooth start.

Comment: Your query, at least as phrased at the moment, is extremely broad and thus not likely to be answerable with anything close to the specificity you appear to be looking for.

Comment: so far not exist one table package, which will cover all what you like to have from them. Each package is dedicated for specific problems. And as @Mico said, your question is to broad.

Comment: @Zarko i am not asking for just one package with all options, need to know hot to combine and use all these packages to my use

Comment: why do you assume they combine? The reason there is more than one package is that you have to choose which features you want. Not all (or even most) combinations of the things you mention are available at all in generally available packages.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle for a normal latex process, different packages are fine, but i am developer who is trying to automate latex typesetting process, for that purpose we generate latex from a XML file, say for instance, the other typesetting software like Arbortext 3b2 has most of the features embedded in a package, I am trying to find out whether latex can function like that, basically i am developing a Auto paginated process for a Latex document to my Specifications, text part i have completed, even Figure part has been almost completed, but i am struggling in tables

Comment: @user52124 -- if you add the rationale you stated in your last comment to the question, and ask instead for a comparison (in table form) of the important features, that would probably be considered an answerable question.

Comment: You may try the new LaTeX3 package `tabularray`: https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray